# Paypal with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am using paypal with codeigniter.

I have paypal credentials, find below -

```
$this->API_USERNAME = '************';
$this->API_PASSWORD = '************';
$this->API_SIGNATURE = '************';
```

My requirement is: Direct send payment to user's paypal email address. I have only user's paypal email address.

I used Paypal_pro codeigniter library but no luck, any suggestion. FInd my code below -

```
$nvpStr = "&EMAILSUBJECT=$emailSubject&RECEIVERTYPE=$receiverType&CURRENCYCODE=$currency";
 $nvpStr.="&L_EMAIL0=$receiverEmail&L_Amt0=$amount&L_ITEMAMT=$amount&L_UNIQUEID0=$uniqueID&L_NOTE0=$note";
$httpParsedResponseAr = $this->paypal_pro->hash_call('MassPay', $nvpStr);
```

Response is-

Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-09-05T17:45:07Z [CORRELATIONID] => 3dfc532f74f43 [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 57.0 [BUILD] => 7560199 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10329 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => User is blocked [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => We're sorry, but your PayPal account isn't currently eligible to send mass payments. Please contact either PayPal Customer Service or your account manager. [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )

but above code works fine with test credentials, find below-

```
$this->API_USERNAME = 'seller_1297608781_biz_api1.lionite.com';
$this->API_PASSWORD = '1297608792';
$this->API_SIGNATURE = 'A3g66.FS3NAf4mkHn3BDQdpo6JD.ACcPc4wMrInvUEqO3Uapovity47p';
```

Then i changed this line-

```
$httpParsedResponseAr = $this->paypal_pro->hash_call('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);
```

But it return below error -

```
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Order total is missing.
```

Can anyone help me whats wrong i did?

Comment: Says it all right here: "We're sorry, but your PayPal account isn't currently eligible to send mass payments. Please contact either PayPal Customer Service or your account manager." Change your code back to when it was working with test credentials and call payPal.

Comment: Order total amount is not passed, please check

Answer (score 0):

MassPay has to be specifically approved and enabled on a live account in order to use it.  The sandbox has access to it without approval so that's why it works fine with your test account.

SetExpressCheckout is the first step in integrating the Express Checkout payment flow into your website or application and its NVP string will be entirely different from what you're trying with MassPay.  The error you got is because there was no AMT parameter included in the string you sent.

If you're simply trying to send money from your own account to another account you can use the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) for that.

I would recommend taking a look at my [CodeIgniter library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/) which will make this very simple for you to setup your Pay request.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.
I can use any paypal method, only requirement isto pay directly to user paypal email.

Can anyone send me demo code that can help me.

Comment: You need to use the Pay API for that like I explained.  The library I linked you to comes with a controller already prepared to do this for you.  All you have to do is plug in your request values.

Comment: The Pay API is part of the Adaptive library / controller.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I downloaded the code but i found some files are missing there, for example itincludes "demo/codeigniter/includes/pay_chained_demo.php" where is these files? demo is not complete...

Comment: Where are you seeing that?  The demo is running [here](http://www.angelleye.com/demo/codeigniter/paypal/adaptive_payments/).